# Is the drum integral to a toner cartridge?

Tags: laser-printer, toner

Is the drum typically integrated into the toner cartridge? I thought the toner cartridge usually contained the primary corona wire and the transfer roller (developer roller), but not the drum.

Comment: I think it depends on the model. What model of printer are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to a question on a test I just got wrong ;)  I said the cartridge included the corona wire and transfer roller. The "correct" answer was corona wire and drum.

Comment: Well I'm rather rusty on such things but certainly that is the standard for many professional devices but I vaguely remember seeing all-in-one units.

Comment: Actually, it's richer than that. Two of the choices were "Toner and Primary Corona" and "Toner and Photosensitive Drum". The professor thinks the second answer is correct.

Comment: usually the toner carts can be replaced without messing with the drum, the allinone (and other) units will have all 3 bundled in a "cartrige" that pulls out, but toner chunk is seperate still. It is an odd question to have without being in a machine (zerox) sponcered class or something, when the variations and interpretation of that would change. I would think the wire stays more with the drum, as i have not yet seen that in a toner cartrige. My interpretation would be D: none of the above are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a current corporate IT tech, most business class laser printers will use a separate Drum Unit and Toner. This allows for them to be replaced separately, as the drum unit can last many times longer than the toner will (assuming you don't have anyone trying to clear jams with a metal ruler - but that's a story for another time). The obviously varies depending on the manufacturer/product line.

As a former employee in the retail industry, I can say that the majority of consumer based laser printers we dealt with had the drum unit integrated into the toner and they both needed to be replaced when the toner ran out. With a shift toward separate drums and toners as the price trended upwards.

As for whether the professor was right or wrong? No idea, that would depend on the specific model of printer they based the exam on.